# Find the earliest and oldest date in a list of dates' string representation

Tags: python

How can I convert this to a Python Date so I can find the latest date in a list?

```
["2018-06-12","2018-06-13", ...] to date
```

Then:

```
max(date_objects)
min(date_objects)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: Edited your title in the hope of making it more specific.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to convert from a list, you'll need to use my linked duplicate with a list comprehension,

```
from datetime import datetime

list_of_string_dates = ["2018-06-12","2018-06-13","2018-06-14","2018-06-15"]

list_of_dates= [datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d") for date in list_of_string_dates]

print(max(list_of_dates)) # oldest
print(min(list_of_dates)) # earliest

2018-06-15 00:00:00
2018-06-12 00:00:00
```

Basically, you're converting the string representation of your dates to a *Python* date using [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and then applying `max` and `min` which are implemented on this type of objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-06-12", "%Y-%m-%d")
date_only = timestamp.date()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. In particular, since your date is in the standard POSIX format, you'll be able to use the function `date.fromtimestamp(timestamp)` to return a datetime object from your string; otherwise, you can use the `strptime` function to read in a more complicated string - that has a few intricacies that you can figure out by looking at the documentation